# Select section by variable

Tags: nsis

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!include "FileFunc.nsh"
!include "LogicLib.nsh"
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ShowInstDetails show
RequestExecutionLevel admin
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name "Test"
Outfile "Test.exe"
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------



LangString DESC_sec1 ${LANG_ENGLISH} "sec1 files"
Section /o "sec1" sec1

SectionEnd

LangString DESC_sec2 ${LANG_ENGLISH} "sec2 files"
Section /o "sec2" sec2

SectionEnd

LangString DESC_sec3 ${LANG_ENGLISH} "sec3 files"
Section /o "sec3" sec3

SectionEnd


Var test
Function .OnInit
  StrCpy $test "sec2"
  !insertmacro SelectSection $test

FunctionEnd
```

How to select section at runtime by section name?
In eample always selected 1st section (think its a bug)

But if i rewrite like this

```
!insertmacro SelectSection ${sec2}
```

All works fine...

Is there way to select section by name from variable?

some long text some long text some long text some long text 
some long text some long text some long text some long text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sections are accessed by their ID which is a number set at compile time:

```
Section "Foo"
SectionEnd
Section "Bar" SID_BAR
SectionEnd
Section "Baz"
SectionEnd

Page Components
Page InstFiles

!include Sections.nsh

Function .onInit
  !insertmacro UnselectSection ${SID_BAR}
FunctionEnd
```

If you want to use the display name then you have to manually enumerate the sections:

```
Section "Foo"
SectionEnd
Section "Bar"
SectionEnd
Section "Baz"
SectionEnd

Page Components
Page InstFiles

!macro GetSectionIdFromName name outvar
Push "${name}"
Call GetSectionIdFromName 
Pop ${outvar} ; ID of section, "" if not found
!macroend
Function GetSectionIdFromName 
Exch $1 ; Name
Push $2
Push $3
StrCpy $2 -1
ClearErrors
loop:
    IntOp $2 $2 + 1
    SectionGetText $2 $3
    IfErrors fail
    StrCmp $3 $1 "" loop
    StrCpy $1 $2
    Goto done
fail:
StrCpy $1 ""
done:
Pop $3
Pop $2
Exch $1
FunctionEnd


!include Sections.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Function .onInit
  StrCpy $1 "Bar" ; The name we are looking for
  !insertmacro GetSectionIdFromName $1 $0
  ${If} $0 != ""
      !insertmacro UnselectSection $0
  ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```